# Align search box & social icons to bottom of a header tag

Tags: html, css

I asked this question the other day and wasn't able to get the solution i needed...

I would like to align the search box and social media icons on either side of the logo area to the bottom of the header (the grey section).  This is so when the user/client of the site wants to swap the logo for their own, no matter the height of it, the search box and social media areas will push themselves to meet the bottom of the header.

Here is a quick example of what I'm trying to get at: 
http://jsfiddle.net/AeRc8/

If someone could please help by illustrating how this is done within a jsfiddle, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an edited version of your jsfiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Shedal/AeRc8/1/

I applied `position: relative` to the `<header>` element and `position: absolute` to the #search and #social elements, with positioning rules corresponding to left-bottom and right-bottom corners.

And of course, removed `float: left` and `float: right`, since this effect is now achieved with absolute positioning.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I have added the necessary changes and you have been very insightful. This is what I will be using to achieve the my desired result and again, placing it into an example with your follow up explanation was very useful.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing like `float:center;`, for further information see the [MDN Docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/float)

`vertical-align` only works in inline-context [MDN Doku](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/CSS/vertical-align)

What you can do, is positioning those two elements absolute like this:

```
#search{
   position:absolute;
   left:0;bottom:0;
}

#search{
   position:absolute;
   right:0;bottom:0;
}
```

Because `position:absolute;` depends on the first ancestor element with position other than `static`, you need to apply `position:relative;` on the container element (in your case the `header`) to make this work.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I have added the necessary changes and you have been very insightful. I thought it was a bit odd reading on here how to align 3 divs and saw someone had suggested float:center;

Answer (score 1):

You can place all the elements which you wish to push down inside a container and then absolutely position it to the bottom of your header, like so:

```
header {
    margin: 0px 29px 29px 29px;
    background: #CCC;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}

.section {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

This way you will have more control over the elements you place inside that section.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AeRc8/2/

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.  I have added the necessary changes and you have been very insightful.  I noticed you added a class with your technique.